# Show ContentDialog before page navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, dialog, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 app, and try to show a log-in dialog (a ContentDialog) before navigating to any page. I try to add the code in `OnLaunched` method in `App.xaml.cs`, but the dialog just doesn't show up:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
...
await new ContentDialog1().ShowAsync();
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(FirstPage), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
}
```

Though if I use a message dialog instead, it would show up just fine. Any advice?

Comment: What's `ContentDialog1` ? How does it look like?

Comment: @Romasz It is a default ContentDialog object. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog(v=win.10).aspx

Comment: I didn't change much. I just added a default ContentDialog class to my project and named it ContentDialog1. All the UI and stuff are default too.

Comment: Can you show your dialog on *Loaded* event of a page? Or you insist on *OnLaunched*, I'm not sure, but your suspicion with lifecycle may be the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't find a `OnLoaded` function in the `App.xaml.cs`, though in a page class it should work. The wired thing is that `MessageDialog` works perfectly fine, and I thought it should have the same mechanism with `ContentDialog`. Apparently there are some subtle differences that I'm not aware of yet

Answer (score 1):

I took another look and it seems like you need to populate the Current Window with a Frame before a ContentDialog can be shown. So you need to reorder the default initialization code a bit. This worked on my setup:

```
    Protected Overrides Async Sub OnLaunched(e As LaunchActivatedEventArgs)
      Dim rootFrame As Frame = New Frame()
      Window.Current.Content = rootFrame
      Window.Current.Activate() '//'Without this the dialog is "shown" but invisible and untouchable :D
      Dim a As New ContentDialog1
      Await a.ShowAsync()
      ...
      rootFrame.Navigate(GetType(MainPage), e.Arguments)
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

'App.OnLaunched' does not run when user returns to your app using the hardwarebackkey or the page history associated with it. You should handle the 'Window.Current.Activated' event.

```
AddHandler Window.Current.Activated, AddressOf WindowActivated

Private Sub WindowActivated(sender As Object, e As Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs)
    Select Case e.WindowActivationState
        Case Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.CodeActivated
            '//'TODO
        Case Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated
            '//'TODO
    End Select
End Sub
```

PS:

You need to navigate somewhere; Maybe to an empty page.

If you don't there is a timeout that will kill your app.

Comment: The OnLaunched method does indeed get called, I tried set a breakpoint in it and it gets hit. And when I replace the ContentDialog with MessageDialog it also shows up. So I don't think that's the problem here.